# Line integrals - Surface area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, area

Here is my task:

Calculate surface area of $2(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}=xy$ between surface $x^{2}+y^{2}=z$ and $z=0$.

Here is my attempt to solve this problem.
Firstly, I transformed line $2(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}=xy$ to polar form, putting $x=\rho\cos \phi$ and $y=\rho\sin \phi$. I got $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}$. It looks like this:

http://s13.postimg.org/wvwox80s7/math.png

To use formula surface_area=$\int z(x,y)ds$ (I don't know how to write line integral symbol in latex so I used symbol for "ordinary" integral instead), we must find first $ds$, which by definitions equals $$ds=\sqrt{(\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} \phi})^{2}+(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} \phi})^{2}}d\phi$$
We have:
$x=\rho\cos \phi=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}\cos\phi$, $y=\rho\sin \phi=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}\sin\phi$. After differentiating $x$ and $y$ with respect to $\phi$ and putting it in expression for $ds$, we get (if I didn't make mistake somewhere in calculations) $ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}}d\phi$. Now we can put everything in our expression for surface area:

$\int z(x,y)ds$=$4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left [ (\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}\cos\phi)^{2} + (\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}\sin\phi)^{2} \right ]\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}}d\phi=4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{4}\sin2\phi(\cos^{2}\phi+\sin^{2}\phi)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}}d\phi=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin{2\phi}}{\sqrt{\sin{2\phi}}}d\phi$

I have no idea how to solve this integral. Any suggestion?

Comment: $2(x^2+y^2)^2=xy$ is not a surface.

Comment: I only did copy/paste of their formulation. But from context of problem, I think it is clear what they mean.

Comment: It's not at all clear.

Comment: Here is 3D plot http://s17.postimg.org/fabjsi42n/Untitled_1.jpg  It looks to me that they want surface area of green figure (between plane z=0 and elliptic paraboloid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PARAMETERIZATION OF SURFACE**

We will use $\phi$ and $z$ to parameterize the surface.  The vector that locates a point on the surface is denoted by

$$\vec r(\phi,z)=\hat \rho(\phi)\rho(\phi)+\hat zz$$

where $\hat \rho$ and $\hat z$ are radial and axial unit vectors, respectively.

We have $\rho(\phi)=\frac12 \sqrt{\sin (2\phi)}$ for $0\le \phi \le \pi/2$ and $\pi\le \phi \le 3\pi/2$.  ______________________________________________________________________

**SURFACE LIMITS**

We will be integrating over $\phi$ and $z$.  Symmetry considerations show that the surface integral over the entire domain is simply four times that over $0\le\phi\le\pi/4$.

We are give that $z$ is bounded below by $z=0$ and above by $z=\rho^2(\phi)=\frac12 \sin(2\phi)$.

The Jacobian $J$ for the surface integral is given by

$$\begin{align}
J&=\left|\frac{\partial \vec r(\phi,z)}{\partial \phi}\times\frac{\partial \vec r(\phi,z)}{\partial z}\right|\\\\
&=\left|(\hat \rho(\phi)\rho(\phi)-\hat \phi(\phi)\rho'(\phi))\times(\hat z)\right|\\\\
&\sqrt{\rho^2(\phi)+\rho'^2(\phi)}
\end{align}$$

where $\rho'(\phi)$ is the derivative of $\rho(\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ and is

$$\rho'(\phi)=\frac12 \frac{\cos(2\phi)}{\sqrt{\sin(2\phi)}}$$

Therefore, we have

$$J=\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(2\phi)}}$$

---

**SURFARCE INTEGRAL**

The surface area $S$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
S&=4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sin(2\phi)/4}\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(2\phi)}}dzd\phi\\\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\sin(2\phi)}d\phi\\\\
&=\frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin(\phi)}d\phi \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Enforcing the substitution $u=\cos^2\phi$, then $du=-2\cos \phi\,\sin \phi\,d\phi$.  We also have $\sin \phi = (1-u)^{1/2}$.  Thus, $(1)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac18\int_0^1 u^{-1/2}(1-u)^{-1/4}du\\\\
&=\frac18\,B(1/2,3/4)\\\\
&=\frac18\,\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\,\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, using the Duplication Formula

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\Gamma(2z)$$

and the functional equation

$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$

reveals that $\Gamma(5/4)=2^{-1/2}\Gamma(3/2)/\Gamma(3/4)=2^{-3/2}\sqrt{\pi}/\Gamma(3/4)$.  Putting it all together yields

$$S=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac14\,\frac{\Gamma^2(3/4)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}$$

Comment: Everything is clear till B and Γ :) What are B and Γ?

Comment: $B$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).